# X11 Issues running with Terminal.app

Tags: bash, x11, ghostscript

I am trying to figure out why I can't use ghostscript or ghostview (or any other X11 applications) when I try to call them in the Terminal. I am using bash, and I also used Fink to get the packages I need. I am using GMT (generic mapping tools), and the commands within this gmt package that don't need x11 run perfectly fine, but when I try to display a postscript, using either the command $ gs or $ gv, I get these error messages, respectively:

```
gv: Unable to open the display. and GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Cannot open X display ':0'. **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
```

I have tried many edits that I've found online, such as adding editing the ~./profile, as shown below:

```
test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh

. /sw/bin/init.sh
export DISPLAY=:0
```

The saving grace here is that if I run the same commands from gmt in xterm (the terminal in X11), the graphic I need is created just fine. All I want to do is have X11 called through the terminal, but right now, I cannot get it working.

Comment: What shell is run inside `Terminal.app`?

Comment: By default it's bash.

Comment: I will give that a try.  Now, I do not have the ./bashrc file.  Should I just make that file and then edit it?  

If I do:

    `$ ls -a`

I get: 

   ` .   .cache   .profile.save  Library
    ..   .config   .recently-used.xbel Movies
    .CFUserTextEncoding .gconf   .rnd   Music
    .DS_Store  .gconfd   Applications  Pictures
    .Trash   .gnome2   Desktop   Public
    .Xauthority  .lesshst  Documents  groupwork
    .bash_history  .profile  Downloads`


So should I also make a bash_profile file?

Comment: I just don't understand how I can use the commands like 'gv' or 'gs' to display a postscript in xterm (X11 terminal), but not in bash?  If I'm working in bash, how and where do I set a path so that the command 'gv' can display the postscript in X11?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Bash, put the same thing in both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. That's what I had to do, at least.

Assuming you're using `fink`, and by all indications of how you've set everything up, it looks like you do.

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea: if you `echo $DISPLAY` in xterm you will get something (let's call it `XXXX`).

In the terminal `export DISPLAY=XXXX`, that should do the trick temporary at least.